# iOS - Cached data used by ALAssetsLibrary is not updated

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary

I seem to be having caching issues with the ALAssetLibrary when testing my app on the iPhone.

Steps used to produce this issue

1. Take a photo using the iPhone camera
2. Access the Camera Roll using ALAssetsLibrary (through [ELCImagePicker](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController))

The problem is that when ELCImagePicker displays the list of albums, the thumbnail of the photo taken in step 1 is displayed for the Camera Roll album (which is correct), but when I go into the Camera Roll album, that photo is not there. An error like this is also displayed in the console log:

```
Cached count is off for 0x2391d0 <x-coredata://D226A7C3-95D5-40B3-BCFB-726E534AB57A/Album/p1> (1357 != 1358) moc=<PLManagedObjectContext: 0x63794c0>
```

1357 and 1358 appears to be match the photo count before and after I take the photo, and closing the image picker and opening it again doesn't help. But if I switch to the Photos app, the photo is displayed there. And when I return to my app, the photo is now displayed as well.

I have tried both

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum ( UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo );
```

and ALAssetsLibrary's

```
(void)writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:(CGImageRef)imageRef orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)orientation completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

but neither works. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification` notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadAlbumGroups) name:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification object:nil];
```

In `reloadAlubmGroups` load your album groups from assets library to get updated objects.

---

Apple Documentation:

> **ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification**
>
> Sent when the contents of the assets library have changed from under the app that is using the data.
>   When you receive this notification, you should discard any cached information and query the assets library again. You should consider invalid any `ALAsset`, `ALAssetsGroup`, or `ALAssetRepresentation` objects you are referencing after finishing processing the notification.
>
> In iOS v4.0, the notification’s object is nil. In iOS v4.1 and later, the notification object is the library object that posted the notification.

Comment: Not exactly the best user experience, but I guess that will have to do since there are not many options available.